# How to create custom alphabetical order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, alphabetical

I have a custom alphabetical order for a custom script I've written. It is defined in the following code, as well as my attempt at specifying an `alphabetize` algorithm, which isn't working.

```js
const symbols = [
  { ascii: "i", unicode: "\u0470" },
  { ascii: "a", unicode: "\u0500" },
  { ascii: "u", unicode: "\u03f0" },

  { ascii: "e", unicode: "\u0410" },
  { ascii: "E", unicode: "\u0450" },
  { ascii: "U", unicode: "\u04a0" },

  { ascii: "I", unicode: "\u03d0" },
  { ascii: "o", unicode: "\u04e0" },
  { ascii: "A", unicode: "\u03b0" },

  { ascii: "O", unicode: "\u04c0" },
  { ascii: "o#", unicode: "\u0390" },
  { ascii: "u#", unicode: "\u0430" },

  { ascii: "e#", unicode: "\u0451" },
  { ascii: "i#", unicode: "\u03d1" },
  { ascii: "a#", unicode: "\u0501" },

  { ascii: "m", unicode: "\u0100" },
  { ascii: "n", unicode: "\u0140" },
  { ascii: "q", unicode: "\u0160" },
  { ascii: "g", unicode: "\u0130" },
  { ascii: "d", unicode: "\u0060" },
  { ascii: "b", unicode: "\u0040" },
  { ascii: "p", unicode: "\u0030" },
  { ascii: "t", unicode: "\u00d0" },
  { ascii: "k", unicode: "\u0050" },

  { ascii: "h", unicode: "\u0120" },
  { ascii: "l", unicode: "\u0170" },
  { ascii: "w", unicode: "\u0110" },

  { ascii: "f", unicode: "\u00c0" },
  { ascii: "s", unicode: "\u0070" },
  { ascii: "C", unicode: "\u00b0" },

  { ascii: "z", unicode: "\u0090" },
  { ascii: "v", unicode: "\u00f0" },
  { ascii: "y", unicode: "\u0180" },

  { ascii: "x", unicode: "\u0190" },
  { ascii: "r", unicode: "\u00e0" },

  { ascii: "c", unicode: "\u0080" },
  { ascii: "j", unicode: "\u0150" },
  { ascii: "Q", unicode: "\u01a0" },

  { ascii: "S", unicode: "\u0072" },
  { ascii: "Z", unicode: "\u0092" },
  { ascii: "H", unicode: "\u0122" },

  { ascii: "'", unicode: "\u01b0" },
]

const alphabet = symbols.map(o => o.ascii)

const words = [
  'He',
  'Hix',
  'Hex',
  'SoHiz',
  'SoH',
  'xo',
  'SoHi',
  'Hi',
  'CU'
]

const alphabetize = (array, alphabet) => {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
      let x = a[i]
      let y = b[i]
      if (y) {
        let diff = alphabet.indexOf(x) - alphabet.indexOf(y)
        if (diff) return diff
      } else {
        return -1
      }
    }
  })
}

console.log(alphabetize(words, alphabet).join('\n'))
```

The output should be:

```
CU
xo
SoH
SoHi
SoHiz
Hi
Hix
He
Hex
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can this become optimal?

Comment: What is the purpose of `unicode` in your structure? It is not used in your code?

Comment: What kind of ASCII character is `o#`?

Comment: @trincot It's not used, sorry I could have deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- if `b[i]` is undefined, then the return value should not be -1, but 1: this will put the shorter `b` before the longer `a`.
- There is a possibility that the `for` loop will complete without a `return` exit. In that case it could be that `a` and `b` are equal or `b` is longer. You need to return a good value for that case.

Here is a correction:

```js
const symbols = [{ ascii: "i", unicode: "\u0470" },{ ascii: "a", unicode: "\u0500" },{ ascii: "u", unicode: "\u03f0" },{ ascii: "e", unicode: "\u0410" },{ ascii: "E", unicode: "\u0450" },{ ascii: "U", unicode: "\u04a0" },{ ascii: "I", unicode: "\u03d0" },{ ascii: "o", unicode: "\u04e0" },{ ascii: "A", unicode: "\u03b0" },{ ascii: "O", unicode: "\u04c0" },{ ascii: "o#", unicode: "\u0390" },{ ascii: "u#", unicode: "\u0430" },{ ascii: "e#", unicode: "\u0451" },{ ascii: "i#", unicode: "\u03d1" },{ ascii: "a#", unicode: "\u0501" },{ ascii: "m", unicode: "\u0100" },{ ascii: "n", unicode: "\u0140" },{ ascii: "q", unicode: "\u0160" },{ ascii: "g", unicode: "\u0130" },{ ascii: "d", unicode: "\u0060" },{ ascii: "b", unicode: "\u0040" },{ ascii: "p", unicode: "\u0030" },{ ascii: "t", unicode: "\u00d0" },{ ascii: "k", unicode: "\u0050" },{ ascii: "h", unicode: "\u0120" },{ ascii: "l", unicode: "\u0170" },{ ascii: "w", unicode: "\u0110" },{ ascii: "f", unicode: "\u00c0" },{ ascii: "s", unicode: "\u0070" },{ ascii: "C", unicode: "\u00b0" },{ ascii: "z", unicode: "\u0090" },{ ascii: "v", unicode: "\u00f0" },{ ascii: "y", unicode: "\u0180" },{ ascii: "x", unicode: "\u0190" },{ ascii: "r", unicode: "\u00e0" },{ ascii: "c", unicode: "\u0080" },{ ascii: "j", unicode: "\u0150" },{ ascii: "Q", unicode: "\u01a0" },{ ascii: "S", unicode: "\u0072" },{ ascii: "Z", unicode: "\u0092" },{ ascii: "H", unicode: "\u0122" },{ ascii: "'", unicode: "\u01b0" },];

const alphabet = symbols.map(o => o.ascii);

const words = ['He','Hix','Hex','SoHiz','SoH','xo','SoHi','Hi','CU']

const alphabetize = (array, alphabet) => {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
      let x = a[i];
      let y = b[i];
      if (y) {
        let diff = alphabet.indexOf(x) - alphabet.indexOf(y);
        if (diff) return diff;
      } else {
        return 1; // <-- corrected
      }
    }
    return a.length - b.length; // is 0 or negative
  })
}

console.log(alphabetize(words, alphabet).join('\n'));
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for a sanity check, is this the "proper" way to implement a custom alphabet sorting? Or is there some fancy algorithm to do it more optimally?

Comment: You can do better by avoiding the repeated `indexOf`: make your alphabet an object keyed by the letters, and with the corresponding order as value (a number). Then you can do a quick lookup with `alphabet[x]` instead of `alphabet.indexOf(x)`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But nothing extra fancy like completely avoiding `array.sort` I take it! :) Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid `array.sort` by implementing a radix sort. The problem is that you have to implement it ... with JavaScript code, and so you will actually lose speed because of that. If it were C, then such a radix sort could be worth it, but not in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, that is good info to know for the future.

Comment: Another approach could be to perform a `replace` on the input strings, replacing each character with another single character (in one `/g` replacement sweep), then sort those with a parameter-less `sort` (alphabetically), and replace the input strings back. So the replacing characters should be such that the sort order will come out correctly. The "first" character should be replaced with "A", the second with "B", ...etc. This pre/post processing is extra work, but you win a lot in the actual sort, as there is no callback to call, so it will run with C-speed.

Comment: [Here](https://bead.chat/term/list) is a list sorted using this technique! (Sorted by the fantasy lang word, which has a [different alphabetical order](https://github.com/tunebond/bead#gematria))

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for when either word is longer than the other

```js
const symbols = [
  { ascii: "i", unicode: "\u0470" },
  { ascii: "a", unicode: "\u0500" },
  { ascii: "u", unicode: "\u03f0" },

  { ascii: "e", unicode: "\u0410" },
  { ascii: "E", unicode: "\u0450" },
  { ascii: "U", unicode: "\u04a0" },

  { ascii: "I", unicode: "\u03d0" },
  { ascii: "o", unicode: "\u04e0" },
  { ascii: "A", unicode: "\u03b0" },

  { ascii: "O", unicode: "\u04c0" },
  { ascii: "o#", unicode: "\u0390" },
  { ascii: "u#", unicode: "\u0430" },

  { ascii: "e#", unicode: "\u0451" },
  { ascii: "i#", unicode: "\u03d1" },
  { ascii: "a#", unicode: "\u0501" },

  { ascii: "m", unicode: "\u0100" },
  { ascii: "n", unicode: "\u0140" },
  { ascii: "q", unicode: "\u0160" },
  { ascii: "g", unicode: "\u0130" },
  { ascii: "d", unicode: "\u0060" },
  { ascii: "b", unicode: "\u0040" },
  { ascii: "p", unicode: "\u0030" },
  { ascii: "t", unicode: "\u00d0" },
  { ascii: "k", unicode: "\u0050" },

  { ascii: "h", unicode: "\u0120" },
  { ascii: "l", unicode: "\u0170" },
  { ascii: "w", unicode: "\u0110" },

  { ascii: "f", unicode: "\u00c0" },
  { ascii: "s", unicode: "\u0070" },
  { ascii: "C", unicode: "\u00b0" },

  { ascii: "z", unicode: "\u0090" },
  { ascii: "v", unicode: "\u00f0" },
  { ascii: "y", unicode: "\u0180" },

  { ascii: "x", unicode: "\u0190" },
  { ascii: "r", unicode: "\u00e0" },

  { ascii: "c", unicode: "\u0080" },
  { ascii: "j", unicode: "\u0150" },
  { ascii: "Q", unicode: "\u01a0" },

  { ascii: "S", unicode: "\u0072" },
  { ascii: "Z", unicode: "\u0092" },
  { ascii: "H", unicode: "\u0122" },

  { ascii: "'", unicode: "\u01b0" },
]

const alphabet = symbols.map(o => o.ascii)

const words = [
  'He',
  'Hix',
  'Hex',
  'SoHiz',
  'SoH',
  'xo',
  'SoHi',
  'Hi',
  'CU'
]

const alphabetize = (array, alphabet) => {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
      let x = a[i]
      let y = b[i]
      if (y && x) {
        let diff = alphabet.indexOf(x) - alphabet.indexOf(y)
        if (diff) return diff
      } else if (y) {
        return -1
      } else {
        return 1
      }
    }
  })
}

console.log(alphabetize(words, alphabet).join('\n'))
```

Comment: Alright phew, banging my head against the wall. I thought I covered it but not the reverse case. Also, is this the "proper" way to implement a custom alphabet? Or is there some fancy algorithm to do it more optimally?

Comment: Wait your code doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: @LancePollard made me do a diff check. It is the expected output